# Classification of hierarchically structured outcomes in R? (hierarchical classification)

Tags: r, machine-learning, bigdata, classification, hierarchical-data

I try to find any **R** implementations that allow to perform **hierarchical classification** (**not** clustering).

The considered classification problems consist of hierarchically nested **outcome** classes. For example, consider the class "sport" (1). Sub-classes of that class could be "basketball" (1.1), "soccer" (1.2), and "tennis" (1.3). But usually more than two classes are nested. For example, the first level could have classes 1 to 4, then we have classes 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, ..., then classes 1.1.1, 1.1.2, ..., and then classes 1.1.1.1, 1.1.1.2, ..., and so on. It is a **tree-structured** classification problem, where each sub-class belongs to exactly one parent class.

Hierarchical classification problems of this kind can be tackled using so-called top-down classification approaches, where conventional multi-class classifiers are applied to each node in the tree. That is, in the example above, one classifier would differentiate between classes 1 to 4, another classifier between classes 1.1, 1.2, and 1.3, another classifier between classes 2.1 to 2.5, and so on. One implementation of this in R was the package "HieRanFor", which seems to have been developed on R-Forge, but it is no longer available. But there also exist special classifiers designed for hierarchical classification problems, so-called big-bang approaches.

Are there any possibilities in R to perform hierarchical classification?

Comment: Sounds similar to divisive cluster analysis where the data is split into two groups, then those groups are split, etc. The package `cluster` has functions `mona` (mona: MONothetic Analysis Clustering of Binary Variables) and `diana` (diana: DIvisive ANAlysis Clustering) that might work for your application.

Comment: Thank you for answer. However, we do not consider clustering, but have fixed outcome classes, which is why we would need to apply a classification algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Mixed effects models are the traditional way to capture hierarchies in a regression model.  The way that the likelihood is expressed creates a preference to keep coefficients of subcategories within a category similar to each other.  There can be any number of layers of hierarchy.  With a binomial family, can perform classification.  `lme4` is the most well-used package for this.

There is probably a better data set to demonstrate this on, but this model for example classifies high efficiency cars by number of cylinders (categorical variable) and car manufacturer within number of cylinders.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lme4)
#> Loading required package: Matrix
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'Matrix'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:tidyr':
#> 
#>     expand, pack, unpack

mpg2 <- mpg %>% 
  mutate(
    high_efficiency = as.factor(cty > 20),
    cyl = as.factor(cyl)
  )

model <- glmer(high_efficiency ~ (1 | cyl / manufacturer), data = mpg2, family = "binomial")

summary(model)
#> Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace
#>   Approximation) [glmerMod]
#>  Family: binomial  ( logit )
#> Formula: high_efficiency ~ (1 | cyl/manufacturer)
#>    Data: mpg2
#> 
#>      AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
#>    119.7    130.1    -56.9    113.7      231 
#> 
#> Scaled residuals: 
#>      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
#> -1.53719 -0.02545 -0.02457 -0.02434  2.66476 
#> 
#> Random effects:
#>  Groups           Name        Variance Std.Dev.
#>  manufacturer:cyl (Intercept)  2.61    1.615   
#>  cyl              (Intercept) 29.89    5.467   
#> Number of obs: 234, groups:  manufacturer:cyl, 32; cyl, 4
#> 
#> Fixed effects:
#>             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
#> (Intercept)   -5.997      5.835  -1.028    0.304

coef(model)
#> $`manufacturer:cyl`
#>              (Intercept)
#> audi:4         -6.832850
#> audi:6         -6.011465
#> audi:8         -5.999128
#> chevrolet:4    -5.963526
#> chevrolet:6    -6.002150
#> chevrolet:8    -6.020727
#> dodge:4        -6.781927
#> dodge:6        -6.020611
#> dodge:8        -6.031986
#> ford:6         -6.013001
#> ford:8         -6.022351
#> honda:4        -3.710665
#> hyundai:4      -6.832850
#> hyundai:6      -6.006829
#> jeep:6         -6.002150
#> jeep:8         -6.005873
#> land rover:8   -6.004195
#> lincoln:8      -6.002512
#> mercury:6      -6.000581
#> mercury:8      -6.000823
#> nissan:4       -5.209047
#> nissan:6       -6.009925
#> nissan:8       -5.999128
#> pontiac:6      -6.003715
#> pontiac:8      -5.999128
#> subaru:4       -7.897771
#> toyota:4       -5.077635
#> toyota:6       -6.017581
#> toyota:8       -6.002512
#> volkswagen:4   -5.152200
#> volkswagen:5   -5.530277
#> volkswagen:6   -6.006829
#> 
#> $cyl
#>   (Intercept)
#> 4 -0.05988493
#> 5 -0.64663800
#> 6 -7.40782848
#> 8 -7.33366858
#> 
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "coef.mer"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, in my case the **outcome** classes are hierarchical and there can be many classes, often hundreds or even thousands of classes. The covariates are just plain metric or binary (dummy-coded), as in conventional regression models.